# Timer_Tick is not a member of an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, timer

I have a `Timer` control and `UpdatePanel` for recheck on some several time. but my problem is why `Timer_Tick` is detected with not a member for my aspx page error message, 
Here my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Timer1_Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="60"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here my problem,

[image]

Here my code behind :

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If UUID <> "" Then

        If UUID = Cardode Then
            scnRFID.Text = CardIdent
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Timer1.Enabled = false

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you define "Timer1_Tick" in code behind file ?

Comment: Well, error seems clear. Do you have method `Timer1_Tick` on the page?

Comment: @Sami Sure, I did, Updated for my post, thank you sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `Timer1_Tick` is private. Internally .aspx file is represented by a class that inherits from code behind class, so private methods are not visible for it.

Make it protected and everything should work fine

Comment: I have changed to public then it's work. But Why its must be public? Thank for your help

Comment: Does not have to be public, protected could do as well. As to why - please see my post, it actually should explain why private is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Change `EventName` from `Timer1_Tick` to `Tick` in `AsyncPostBackTrigger` like this:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
```

Also you need to change the `Timer1_Tick` [Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)  from private to protected.

Comment: I have done for change but its still problem, may this is protection issue. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @MafullahBacktrack...protected should works. You're Welcome.